# How can I Change the default Icon of a JPanel based swing app (or window)

Tags: java, swing, icons

I've seen many answers for this question when it's a `JFrame`, but none for `JPanel`, and all that I've tried didn't work.

So basically I've written this simple class/app that extends `JPanel`, and all is working fine.  Now I'd like to change the Default Icon.

Any ideas?

Comment: A panel can't be made visible without being embedded inside a window (JFrame, JDialog, JWindow). What do you  want to do exactly?

Comment: A JPanel is only a container but no window, so there must be a JFrame, JDialog or JApplet around it.

Comment: ok, thanks for your correction. I didn't notice the JFrame, now I do. I tried to vote to close it, but the dialog gave me a multiple choices to select from, none of them is relevant to my case, although someone chose "not a real question"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as guys are saying here in comments please reconsider what you are trying to do. 
The only option to change an icon is to set it for the frame in which the panel is child, since the icon is a part/belongs to the frame.

If you want setting of the icon to be a functionality of a panel then in addNotify() method, which is called when a component receives a parent, look through the panel's parent and it parent and so on until you will reach the frame and set the icon for it.

Sample showing a number of parent you must go through to get to frame if a panel is its content pane.

```
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setContentPane(p);
        System.out.println(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(p));
```

Comment: ok, figured this one now, there was a another class which had the JFrame, thanks!

Comment: use SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...) to get the frame, not the getParent() method.

Comment: @camickr I didn't know of its existence. Lesson learnt. Cheers.:)